# Can not uninstall tensorflow and keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

When I type in the command

```
pip uninstall keras
pip uninstall tensorflow

root@a26-03-06:/data01/yanan/keras# pip uninstall keras
DEPRECATION: Python 3.4 support has been deprecated. pip 19.1 will be the last one supporting it. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.4 won't be maintained after March 2019 (cf PEP 429).
Skipping keras as it is not installed.
root@a26-03-06:/data01/yanan/keras# pip uninstall tensorflow
DEPRECATION: Python 3.4 support has been deprecated. pip 19.1 will be the last one supporting it. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.4 won't be maintained after March 2019 (cf PEP 429).
Skipping tensorflow as it is not installed.
```

And I can not find them in pip list. When I import them, they exists. So how can I uninstall them?

The version of python is 2.7.

Comment: Your pip is controlling python3.4 packages, and your Keras and Tensorflow is installed in python2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have mentioned in the Comment above, your Pip package manager is linked with python3 installation and you need to do changes in python 2.7, One way to do that is use

`python -m pip unistall keras tensorflow` this works in windows and should in Linux, If it doesn't work try uninstalling them separately rather than a single statement.